# Как отправить эмбед в дискорде? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Всем привет. Задался следущим вопросом при разработке Discord бота на языке Python. Как можно отравить эмбед сообщение?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте:

```
embedHelp = discord.Embed(title='Команды помощи', description='Нужны команды бота? Без проблем! Смотрите ниже..', color=discord.Color.blue)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ChessPro не за что)